# Read callback data in new thread C#

Tags: multithreading, callback, icallbackeventhandler

Can someone help me, I have one method that I call to "activate" callback method(which is set to send me changed data every second) and second method(which is "activated" by first) that runs every second and give me data. That is all fine, but I need that second method run in new thread and after couple days of trying and reading I couldn't mange to do that. Can someone please guide me how to do that? here is my code.

```
    int ItemNumItems;
    Array ItemClientHandles;
    Array ItemServerValues;
    Array ItemQualities;
    Array ItemTimeStamps;

    public void Callback()
    {
        //Here I add a delegate with method to be called on data change.

        Grupa1.DataChange += new DIOPCGroupEvent_DataChangeEventHandler(Grupa1_DataChange);
    }

    void Grupa1_DataChange(int TransactionID, int NumItems, ref Array ClientHandles, ref Array ItemValues, ref Array Qualities, ref Array TimeStamps)
    {
        //Here I read my data and pass them to my variables(and this is 
        //runned every second) and I want this method to run in new thread.

        ItemNumItems = NumItems;
        ItemClientHandles = ClientHandles;
        ItemServerValues = ItemValues;
        ItemQualities = Qualities;
        ItemTimeStamps = TimeStamps;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that maybe:

```
void Grupa1_DataChange(int TransactionID, int NumItems, ref Array ClientHandles, ref Array ItemValues, ref Array Qualities, ref Array TimeStamps)
{
    Array tmpClientHandles = ClientHandles;
    Array tmpItemValues = ItemValues;
    Array tmpQualities = Qualities;
    Array tmpTimeStamps = TimeStamps;

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        //Here I read my data and pass them to my variables(and this is 
        //runned every second) and I want this method to run in new thread.

        ItemNumItems = NumItems;
        ItemClientHandles = tmpClientHandles;
        ItemServerValues = tmpItemValues;
        ItemQualities = tmpQualities;
        ItemTimeStamps = tmpTimeStamps;
   });
}
```

?

But why to you want to run it asynchronously?

From the code you show there is nothing that will gain to being run in parallel.

Comment: You are right about not gaining anything but I got an assignment to do that so I have to. :) But it will not work like that, I get: Error 1  Delegate 'System.Threading.WaitCallback' does not take 0 argument and for all arrays Error 2  Cannot use ref or out parameter 'ClientHandles' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression

Comment: I've fixed the first error. Do you really need to pass them by "ref"? Anyway you could use temporaries, I'll update my answer.

Comment: First I must say thanks for help. That method Grupa1_DataChange must be like that(with ref) because it is an instance of delegate DIOPCGroupEvent_DataChangeEventHandler that is defined like that and I can't change it. (It reads data from some OPC server, but that is not important)

Comment: Does my update (with copy of "ref" params into temporaries) fits your requirements?